# How to make Callable wait till execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, task, callable

I have One Callable which I invoked using

```
FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(new MyCallable(name, type));
pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
pool.submit(task);
```

I want to know Is execution is continue after `pool.submit(task)` or It will wait for callable to complete its execution?

In short I just want to know is there any method like `thread.join()` for Callable?

Comment: `task.get()` will wait for the task to complete. Is it what you are looking for?. When you `submit` the task is going asynchronous in to the thread(s) managed by the `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ... is there any method like thread.join() for Callable?

The `pool.submit(callable)` method returns a `Future` and will start executing immediately if the threads are available in the pool.  To do a `join`, you can call `future.get()` which joins with the thread, returning the value returned by the `call()` method.  It is important to note that `get()` may throw an `ExecutionException` if the `call()` method threw.

You do not *need* to wrap your `Callable` in a `FutureTask`.  The thread-pool does that for you.  So your code would be:

```
pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<String> future = pool.submit(new MyCallable(name, type));

// now you can do something in the foreground as your callable runs in the back

// when you are ready to get the background task's result you call get()
// get() waits for the callable to return with the value from call
// it also may throw an exception if the call() method threw
String value = future.get();
```

This is if your `MyCallable` implements `Callable<String>` of course.  The `Future<?>` will match whatever type your `Callable` is.

Comment: Thanks Gray: Can you tell me What type of exceptions can Callable throws..?

Comment: You can look at the Javadocs @milind_ensarm. The `ExecutionException` is the one that is not a runtime exception. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()

Answer (score 1):

`task.get()` (task being a `FutureTask`) expects the current thread to wait for the completion of the managed task by the thread pooler.

This method ends up returning either a concrete result or throwing the same checked exception (although wrapped into an ExecutionException) that the job thread would throw during its task.